# Why the $.ajax() method cannot be called inside $('selector').delegate() method in this piece of code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I was looking for a way to select elements that we echoed by PHP using JS.
I found out there is a way by using "delegate()". So, here I am trying to select the element which is clicked upon, then retrieve details corresponding to it from the database.

The console prints "Error!"

Is there something that I am missing. I am still learning jQuery. Is there any other way to do what I am trying to do?

NOTE: Also for some reason, this script does not work in an external JS file.

This is  the script I wrote

```
   $("body").delegate( "li.allfriends", "click", function() {

        var friend = $(this).html();
        var username = "<?php echo $_SESSION['user'] ?>";

        var data = { 'action': 'showExpenses', 'username': username, 'friend': friend };
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            method: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Success!');
                console.log(data);
            }, 
            error: function (error) {
                console.log('Error!');
            }
        });
    });
```

This is where I am processing it

```
if($_POST['action'] == 'showExpenses') {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $friend = $_POST['friend'];

    $rows = $misc->showExpensesForSelectedFriend($username, $friend); 
    return json_encode($result); 
}
```

This is the final function where I am retrieving data

```
public function showExpensesForSelectedFriend($username, $friend) {
    $username = $this->sql->escape($username);
    $friend = $this->sql->escape($friend);

    $rows1 = $this->sql->getDatas('expense', 'paidBy', $username, 'owedBy', $friend);
    $rows2 = $this->sql->getDatas('expense', 'paidBy', $friend, 'owedBy', $username);
    foreach($rows2 as &$item) {
        array_push($rows1, $item);
    }
    return $rows1;
}
```

Console prints Error!, Later I checked showExpensesForSelectedFriend() was working fine.

Comment: What's the problem with the code? Any errors? Does the request go out, or is there a response?

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using? Since jQuery 1.7 `.delegate()` is deprecated and `.on()` has superceded it. 

https://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: Really need more info on what errors you are getting in regards to why you think its not working. Devtools console should either show an error, or a Success! or Error! log. You have provided nothing to know where to even begin looking.

Comment: Check the network tab as well, when the ajax call fires off, it should hit the server. If its returning a status code 500, your PHP is breaking. Which you will need to debug further and turn on more error reporting in PHP to find.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I ran it and console printed "Error!"

Comment: @IncredibleHat You are right  the console is printing "Error!". What could be the problem?

Comment: Thank u guys. Finally i found the error. The error was in "return json_encode()" part. It should be "echo json_enode()". But I still cannot reason why this does not work in external JS file. @IncredibleHat

Comment: I glazed over the return... wasn't sure it was inside a method (many people post content of class methods, and not the entire class to keep it brief).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this should be your problem. `json_encode($result);` try to make this variable into an `array` like this.

```
if($_POST['action'] == 'showExpenses') {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $friend = $_POST['friend'];
    $rows = $misc->showExpensesForSelectedFriend($username, $friend);
    $result = array();
    if(count($rows) == 0) {
        $result['status'] = 0;
    } 
    return json_encode($result); 
}
```

You can call the return value such `data.status`.

```
   $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            method: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Success!');
                console.log(data.status);
            }, 
            error: function (error) {
                console.log('Error!');
            }
        });
```

Comment: This makes a successful match of rows return an empty object without any status being set to 1. As a side note it is perfectly fine in PHP to initialize an array variable with its first key=value as `$result['status'] = 1;` You do not have to do `$result = array();` first (although its good to purge $result before working with it).

Comment: Thanks @IncredibleHat, but the result is same. But i found the error. It finally worked. The error was in "return json_encode()" part. It should be "echo json_enode()"